# Include resources in transactions

Tags: spring

I am trying to find a way to make sure custom resources like files that are created within a transaction (using @Transactional) are cleaned up in case that transaction rolls back. I tried implementing a custom TransactionManager but could not find a way to register it but I do know for example spring-rabbitmq has its own transaction manager that taps into the existing transactions. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I got you correctly, but according to tag name you are using spring.

You can handle it via **Spring AOP**.

You should just create your own annotation(e.g. **YourOwnTransactional**) , and check it.

If annotation exists, you can just call like :

```
@Around(@anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(YourOwnTransactional))
public void aroundAddAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp){
  try{
    pjp.proceed();
  }catch(YourException e){
    //rollback
  }
}
```

**edited.**

Comment: Thanks but that is not what I asked. I am creating files within a transaction and want to implement a way of cleaning those up on a rollback by creating a custom transaction manager or similar. Basically, imagine you create an image and store a reference to it in the database in the transaction - but the transaction fails because of some exception and you want the file you created to be cleaned up as well. I want to do this automatically by tapping in to the transaction model.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Not sure what do you mean when saying "transaction model" , but you can handle any kind of rollback for any annotation with RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME.

Comment: Yes I have thought about that myself too, but I think there is a way to tap into the transaction management that spring provides already (the one that already has aspects for @Transactional). There is the PlatformTransactionManager interface but I can´t find any way to use it properly as there is no documentation on how to hook it up. I guess I will have to go through the spring-rabbitmq source as they have done exactly that.